# Carousel appearing as separate images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to make a carousel with Bootstrap for a sales site, but it doesn't seem to be turning on.

I've looked through the code and everything seems to match the example given on their site, but it just appears as four images stacked one above the other and the previous and back buttons at the bottom.

Clicking those buttons does change the `active` tag through the various photos when looked at on developer tools, but there just doesn't seem to be anything happening visually.

I'm looping through database pictures if that's an issue, but these seem to be appearing and present in the right places. Cheers.

Here's the code if that helps:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide pointer-event" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li><li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li><li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">

              <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="img/5c93c5fec0d110.10065506.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Absolute Balderdash">
              </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/5c93c5fec16a35.12174898.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Absolute Balderdash">
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/5c93c5fec1c830.06571881.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Absolute Balderdash">
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/5c93c5fec20b53.10796324.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Absolute Balderdash">
          </div>
            </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 0):

There is no error at all. You might have to check if you have to insert required libraries.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide pointer-event" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120.jpg?text=First" class="d-block w-100" alt="Absolute Balderdash">
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120.jpg?text=Second" class="d-block w-100" alt="Absolute Balderdash">
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120.jpg?text=Third" class="d-block w-100" alt="Absolute Balderdash">
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120.jpg?text=Fourth" class="d-block w-100" alt="Absolute Balderdash">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is my header
    <html lang="en" class="gr__getbootstrap_com"><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Elmtree Exchange</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
    
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="user.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <style type="text/css">
          body {
            padding-top: 60px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
          }
        </style>

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: And that's the bottom

Comment: your `src="xyz"` is a mistake, you have to supply protocol else it will be searched with your domain's local folder. like your link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css", so your js src should be `src="https://xyz"`. For your satisfaction check developer toolbars network panel and the requests happening for the above src files.

Comment: Ah right! Perfect, I'll give that a go and hopefully that sorts it out! You've been a great help! Thanks a million!